# Counting number of digits for numbers between two nonzero numberes in each string of list of strings

Tags: python, list, count

I am trying to count the number of digits  for numbers between two nonzero numbers in each string (including the two numbers) in list of strings. What I mean by this is that I am trying not to count zeros that are next to other zeros but do count zeros that are between other nonzero numbers. For example:

```
['', '', '000000000100111101', '', '', '0000112112111101011100000000001', '', '', '', '', '',]
```

From the list of strings above, I would like to not count 000000000 from 000000000100111101 and only count 100111101
So the expected output I would like to get is

```
[0 0 9 0 0 27 0 0 0 0 0]
```

I would greatly appreciate anyone's help thank you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen although similar it is a different question; that one did not require pre-processing the inputs. Agree with you about the accepting part though...

Answer (score 2):

You can simply compute the length of each string with the `0`s [`stripped`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) off each end:

```py
nums = ['', '', '000000000100111101', '', '', '0000112112111101011100000000001', '', '', '', '', '',]
[len(num.strip('0')) for num in nums]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```